# Gstreamer splitmuxsink callback when a new file is created

Tags: callback, gstreamer

I have a gst pipeline for recording video with splitmuxsink set to create new file every hour. I would like to have some callback when the new file is created.
I have tried
GstElement *sink = gst_element_factory_make ("splitmuxsink", "sink");

```
 g_object_set (sink, "max-size-bytes", 4294967295, NULL);
 g_object_set (sink, "max-size-time", 3600000000000, NULL); // 3600000000000 - 1 hour

 g_signal_connect (sink, "split-now",G_CALLBACK(split_now_callback_test), &data);
```

However i found out, that "split-now" is signal which I can pass to the splitmuxsink and not the other way around. Is there a relatively easy way to have some callback a new target file is created?

Answer (score 1):

There is a message that is emitted by the `splitmuxsink` element when it opens or closes a new fragment: "splitmuxsink-fragment-opened" or "splitmuxsink-fragment-closed". I found these messages in the [splitmuxsink source code](https://github.com/GStreamer/gst-plugins-good/blob/master/gst/multifile/gstsplitmuxsink.c) (search for the `gst_element_post_message` function call to see where the message is sent).

Here's [an SO question about](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34594273/gstmultifilesink-post-messages-callback) of listening for element messages (from the `multifilesink` element, which is very similar to the `splitmuxsink` element). In particular, see [this gist](https://gist.github.com/aultimus/cce26f5879ac9075cb4d) from the OP on that question for an example of how to implement this in C.

I didn't validate that the approach above works in C, as I used this `splitmuxsink` message in a Rust implementation of the pipeline, but I think the general idea, translated to C, is something like this (adapted from [GStreamer basic tutorial #3](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/tutorials/basic/dynamic-pipelines.html?gi-language=c)):

```c
/* Listen to the bus */
bus = gst_element_get_bus (data.pipeline);
do {
  msg = gst_bus_timed_pop_filtered (bus, GST_CLOCK_TIME_NONE,
      GST_MESSAGE_ELEMENT | GST_MESSAGE_ERROR | GST_MESSAGE_EOS);

  /* Parse message */
  if (msg != NULL) {
    GError *err;
    gchar *debug_info;

    switch (GST_MESSAGE_TYPE (msg)) {
      case GST_MESSAGE_ERROR:
        gst_message_parse_error (msg, &err, &debug_info);
        g_printerr ("Error received from element %s: %s\n", GST_OBJECT_NAME (msg->src), err->message);
        g_printerr ("Debugging information: %s\n", debug_info ? debug_info : "none");
        g_clear_error (&err);
        g_free (debug_info);
        terminate = TRUE;
        break;
      case GST_MESSAGE_EOS:
        g_print ("End-Of-Stream reached.\n");
        terminate = TRUE;
        break;
      case GST_MESSAGE_ELEMENT:
        /* Handle element-specific message here */
        break;
      default:
        /* We should not reach here */
        g_printerr ("Unexpected message received.\n");
        break;
    }
    gst_message_unref (msg);
  }
} while (!terminate);
```

For more info on element messages and the GstBus, see [this page](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/application-development/basics/bus.html?gi-language=c#how-to-use-a-bus) of the GStreamer docs